# Analyze network usage amount with Linux

Tags: linux, networking

Sometimes when working in the office our internet connection becomes unusable. I'm not sure weather it's the actual internet connection or if our internal network is overflowed with data.

Most of the machines is running OS X and connected through Wifi. My machine is running Linux and connected with Wifi. I have another desktop machine running Linux connected with cable.

The setup is somewhat like this

```
                                         /-D(cable) the desktop Linux machine
                                /-C(NAT) -E(wifi) any number of wifi connected devices
                   /-B(cable) - Unknown devices
internet - (NAT) -
                   \-A(wifi) any number of wifi connected devices
```

I know for sure that the problem does not lie in the C-part of the network.

I can connect to point A with my laptop. But not without hassle to point B.

**Question**: How can I analyse traffic on A and B with Linux. Preferably my Laptop over wifi. I only need to know amount of traffic and source/destination. Like 10mbit of traffic come and goes to this machine.

Comment: to do this, you need control of the routers/switches, or at least the ability to put the switches in promiscuous mode. this kind of analysis is somthing you have to do from an intermediary system, not a client. Do you have the blessing of your IT dept? if so, ask them about MRTG.

Comment: Yes, that is no problem. It's a small office. However, I'm not sure what software I should use.

Comment: check out MRTG: http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/